# "distance" metric between two bases modulo determinant, rotation and chirality

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces

I'd like some kind of metric that tells me how similar two complete, not necessarily orthonormal bases (represented by non-singular matrices $B_1, B_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$) are to each other, if the rotation, chirality and the magnitude $b_i^*b_i$ of the determinants $det\left(B_i\right)$ don't matter.

The metric should roughly tell you how much you have to skew one basis (i.e. change the angles between its vectors and change their lengths) to turn it into the other basis, disregarding a global rotation, reflection or scale.

The purpose really is to decide whether a given basis is closer to, say, a face-centered cubic unit cell or a body centered cubic one, etc.

Is there a neat metric that does just this?

EDIT: Followup question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270404/49989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to think in terms of linear transformations. So, $B_i$ is the matrix of linear transformation that maps the standard basis to the basis represented by $B_i$. Then $T=B_2B_1^{-1}$ is the transformation that maps the first basis to the second. You'd like to know how far it is from being a composition of rotation, reflection, and scaling.

There are several *distortion functions* invented exactly for this purpose. The best known one is the condition number
$$K_T = \|T\|\|T^{-1}\|$$
(using an operator norm associated to Euclidean vector norm.) It is equal to $1$ if and only if $T$ is the composition of scaling, rotation, and reflection. Otherwise it's greater than $1$.

Since $K_{ST}\le K_SK_T$, the logarithm of  $K_T$ provides a metric on the space of equivalence classes of bases: it obeys the triangle inequality.

See also: [Banach–Mazur compactum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_compactum).

Comment: Ack, I just realized it's not gonna be that simple with lattices possibly being distorted in all kinds of ways - how could I possibly exhaustively test for a triclinic lattice (other than "well it's none of the others" - which would be hard to test as well for anything but the cubic lattices.) Anyway, at least for the cubic lattices it works well and it's at least a good start. Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for. If you have further ideas I'd gladly take suggestions but now I'm a little stumped.

Comment: Your question didn't say anything about lattices... I suggest asking a new question that includes the lattice aspect of your problem.

Comment: yeah, I will. Just gotta reconsider what exactly I need. - The problem basically is "given a random basis, what kind of lattice does it most closely resemble?" - which is easy enough to do with what you gave me in case of all the cubic lattices, but all others may contain too many degrees of freedom (i.e. more than zero, outside of rotation, reflection or scale) to distill them down to a single example lattice I could compare my basis to. It's late now though. I'll try to write another question tomorrow. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I asked a new question. It's rather different in scope from this one I think, but here is hoping you may be able to help me again. I added a link to the new question at the end of this question.